can we found parent table from remote view that owning on blank DBC
i have remoteview from pinjaman.dbc, on this dbc have 5 table, 51 local view and 1 remote view. one of local view displayed on view design. it is need open table on this dbc. and i got warning like 'cannot find object debitur on database' also file 'debitur.dbf' does not exist. what should i do all about this problems. also i wanna know parent table from this local view.
enter image description here
i wanna know parent table from dbc that contain local view and remote view..

Get your views' definitions in code, so you could check what it is referring to. To do that you could use gendbc. ie:
Open Database pinjaman
Do home()+'tools\gendbc\gendbc' with 'MyDatabaseAsCode.prg'

After you run these lines in command window, you would have 'MyDatabaseAsCode.prg' generated in current folder. Edit it to see the definition of your 'afalis' view and others. That 'debitur' might have been referenced in many places (a select, a trigger ...).
PS: Please avoid unnecessary picture sharing. Use text instead. Pictures are not very welcomed on SO.
